# Dynamic locale segment based on domain extension with Next.js

Tags: next.js

The current Next.js project supports locales following this pattern

```
https://example.com/en-US
https://example.com/it-IT
https://example.com/be-FR
https://example.com/be-NL
```

with this pattern, we manage by the Next.js locale feature without any issues.
but the SEO team asked us to remove locale and support different domains like:

```
https://example.com
https://example.it
https://example.be/fr
https://example.be/nl
```

Is it possible to manage different URL patterns based on locale with next.js?
We are using Pages Router and planning to upgrade to App Router soon

With Pages Router, we are able somehow to manage locales leveraging on middleware but with App Router, as the locale is dynamic, we are facing some issues in implementing it